# Why does Mapbox request ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission when it's not needed?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

Our app needs to display maps independent of the user's location, but the Play Console reports that the app is requesting the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission (which is not in the app's manifest). The only Mapbox dependency lines used are:

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.3.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v9:0.8.0'
```

Looking at the manifest merge output shows that the permission is being requested by the manifest added by the main Mapbox SDK dependency. In it is this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Is there a way to use the Mapbox SDK without having the app request the unneeded permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, as reported by the Mapbox support team, is to just remove the undesired permission from the app's manifest file:

```
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" 
    tools:node="remove" />
```